# more advantages or disadvantages to delegate members over classic functions?

Tags: c#, class, function, delegates, abstraction

```
class my_class
{
    public int add_1(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
    public func<int, int, int> add_2 = (a, b) => {return a + b;}
}
```

add_1 is a function whereas add_2 is a delegate. However in this context delegates can forfill a similar role.

Due to precedent and the design of the language the default choice for C# methods should be functions.

However both approaches have pros and cons so I've produced a list. Are there any more advanteges or disadvantages to either approach?

Advantages to conventional methods.

- more conventional
- outside users of the function see named parameters - for the add_2 syntax arg_n and a type is generally not enough information.
- works better with intellisense - ty Minitech
- works with reflection - ty Minitech
- works with inheritance - ty Eric Lippert
- has a "this" - ty CodeInChaos
- lower overheads, speed and memory - ty Minitech and CodeInChaos
- don't need to think about public\private in respect to both changing and using the function. - ty CodeInChaos
- less dynamic, less is permitted that is not known at compile time - ty CodeInChaos

Advantages to "field of delegate type" methods.

- more consistant, not member functions and data members, it's just all just data members.
- can outwardly look and behave like a variable.
- storing it in a container works well.
- multiple classes could use the same function as if it were each ones member function, this would be very generic, concise and have good code reuse.
- straightforward to use anywhere, for example as a local function.
- presumably works well when passed around with garbage collection.
- more dynamic, less must be known at compile time, for example there could be functions that configure the behaviour of objects at run time.
- as if encapsulating it's code, can be combined and reworked, [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175%28v=vs.80%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- outside users of the function see unnamed parameters - sometimes this is helpfull although it would be nice to be able to name them.
- can be more compact, in this simple example for example the return could be removed, if there were one parameter the brackets could also be removed.
- roll you'r own behaviours like inheritance - ty Eric Lippert
- other considerations such as functional, modular, distributed, (code writing, testing or reasoning about code) etc...

Please don't vote to close, thats happened already and it got reopened. It's a valid question even if either you don't think the delegates approach has much practical use given how it conflicts with established coding style or you don't like the advanteges of delegates.

Comment: Are you aware that the second example is not a function? It's a delegate.

Comment: If you want to return void then you use `Action<>` instead of `Func<>`

Comment: Where did you see this offered as a choice?

Comment: An example on why this is horrible? my_class a = new my_class(); a.add_2 = null; a.add_2(1, 2); ----- NullReferenceException! AHHHH!

Comment: I don't see why this was closed. It's a perfectly reasonable question about the competing factors in designing implementation details of a class. **I frequently use this technique in my own programs because it has real advantages** -- namely, that it allows me to very easily decide which methods in a function have memoization applied to them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: A delegate wraps a function.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti: So use the `readonly` keyword, or a `private` setter.

Comment: @EricLippert: I agree that it's a good and interesting question.  But it probably doesn't meet the SO guidelines.  Questions of this nature lead to discussion, subjective answers, and partial answers, which qualify it for closure.

Comment: Why you should do something like this just to write a function, this will make everyone that look at your code spend months in understand WHY

Comment: I'd avoid the second for public members. For internal code it can be useful (especially when made `static readonly`) .

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti: Unless they've used delegates with any regularity.  Or Javascript, in which methods are defined in quite the same way.

Comment: yes :) indeed. Horrible way to write code from my point of view.

Comment: @alan2here: If you actually reseat the delegate, you can close over the equivalent of `this`, and you'll get the same benefit.

Comment: My greatest concern about this code, and the way the question was answered, is the feeling that the OP thinks that the two are equivalent, as they would be if this were JavaScript.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I think Javascript has no option 1, since you can reseat "methods", and all calls will be runtime dynamic.  Seeing that he's got a somewhat accurate and sizable list of pros and cons, I'm not sure the OP is missing anything, besides maybe fear of going against the grain and losing some perf/safety :)  If you want some validation from people answering though, users of such code (that replaced every method with option 2) would be *very* surprised, and possibly pissed off, since it might flush away a lot of tooling and perf for potentially little gain.

Comment: JavaScript does have methods, just not classes. And what the OP is missing is that the pros for method 2 don't matter, except in a tiny fraction of cases. The question is asked as though the two might be equivalent: they're not, unless you are required do solve one of that tiny fcaction of cases.

Comment: I doubt that a functional programmer will like your public mutable field.

Comment: Fixed CodeInChaos. I was thinking of the use of functions as parameters to functions and the such, but probbably, havn't done much functional. I've taken that line out, if you can think of a way of including something similar but true I will add it instead :¬P

Comment: Current version of answer: I think eric mentioned overloading, not inheritance.  Also, you can use delegates to return void - just use `Action` instead of `Func` as @Hogan mentioned.

Comment: Voting to close. See Ben Voight's comment. I like the answers to this question, but *the way it is asked* requires a subjective answer.  SO questions should never simply ask for more discussion, and they shouldn't be buckets to throw data into.  Having the bucket is useful, but should not be the main question.  SO questions should ask for a definitive answer against a specific question.  A way to rephrase this question to get an objective answer (which is the question nearly everyone answered, even though it wasn't asked): "Why wouldn't someone replace every method definition with a delegate?"

Comment: I've recently updated the introduction of the question Merlyn. But not as you proposed as it seems like a very biased way of asking it. Also note that it's been closed before and swiftly re-opened. ty Hogan, I've just actioned your comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, the "high order bit" for me with regards to this design decision would be that I would never do this sort of thing with a *public* field/method. At the very least I would use a *property*, and probably not even that.

For private fields, I use this pattern fairly frequently, usually like this:

```
class C
{
    private Func<int, int> ActualFunction = (int y)=>{ ... };
    private Func<int, int> Function = ActualFunction.Memoize();
```

and now I can very easily test the performance characteristics of different memoization strategies without having to change the text of ActualFunction at all.

Another advantage of the "methods are fields of delegate type" strategy is that you can implement code sharing techniques that are different than the ones we've "baked in" to the language. A protected field of delegate type is essentially a *virtual method*, but more flexible. Derived classes can replace it with whatever they want, and you have emulated a regular virtual method. But you could build custom inheritence mechanisms; if you really like prototype inheritance, for example, you could have a convention that if the field is null, then a method on some prototypical instance is called instead, and so on.

A major disadvantage of the methods-are-fields-of-delegate-type approach is that of course, overloading no longer works. Fields must be unique in name; methods merely must be unique in signature.  Also, you don't get generic fields the way that we get generic methods, so method type inference stops working.

Comment: I tried to get around the overloading disadvantage once by defining a delegate type (in IL) that has multiple `Invoke` methods. It could actually work, except unfortunately C# doesn't work with delegate syntax and requires `.Invoke` to be called explicitly for that class...

Comment: I like the mention of a property instead of a field, tho not quite enough for an upvote.  Are there other disadvantages that would make you "probably not even [use a property]"?  You say what you would choose, but you don't mention a lot of reasons why.  I take a stab at this in my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Why you should avoid delegates as methods by default, and what are alternatives:

*Learning curve*

Using delegates this way will surprise a lot of people.  Not everyone can wrap their head around delegates, or why you'd want to swap out functions.  There seems to be a learning curve.  Once you get past it, delegates seem simple.

*Perf and reliability*

There's a performance loss to invoking delegates in this manner.  This is another reason I would default to traditional method declaration unless it enabled something special in my pattern.

There's also an execution safety issue.  Public fields are nullable.  If you're passed an instance of a class with a public field you'll have to check that it isn't null before using it.  This hurts perf and is kind of lame.

You can work around this by changing all public fields to properties (which is a rule in all .Net coding standards anyhow).  Then in the setter throw an `ArgumentNullException` if someone tries to assign `null`.

*Program design*

Even if you can deal with all of this, allowing methods to be mutable at all goes against a lot of the design for static OO and functional programming languages.

In static OO types are always static, and dynamic behavior is enabled through polymorphism.  You can know the exact behavior of a type based on its run time type.  This is very helpful in debugging an existing program.  Allowing your types to be modified at run time harms this.

In both static OO and function programming paradigms, limiting and isolating side-effects [is quite helpful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), and using [fully immutable structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) is one of the primary ways to do this.  The only point of exposing methods as delegates is to create mutable structures, which has the exact opposite effect.

*Alternatives*

If you really wanted to go so far as to always use delegates to replace methods, you should be using a language like [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) or something else built on top of the DLR.  Those languages will be tooled and tuned for the paradigm you're trying to implement.  Users and maintainers of your code won't be surprised.

That being said, there are uses that justify using delegates as a substitute for methods.  You shouldn't consider this option unless you have a compelling reason to do so that overrides these performance, confusion, reliability, and design issues.  You should only do so if you're getting something in return.

#### Uses

- For private members, [Eric Lippert's answer describes a good use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028774/232593): ([Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).
- You can use it to [implement a Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in a function-based manner rather than requiring a class hierarchy.  Again, I'd use private members for this...

...Example code:

```
public class Context
{
    private Func<int, int, int> executeStrategy;

    public Context(Func<int, int, int> executeStrategy) {
        this.executeStrategy = executeStrategy;
    }

    public int ExecuteStrategy(int a, int b) {
        return executeStrategy(a, b);
    }
}
```

- I have found a particular case where I think public delegate properties are warrented: To implement a [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) with instances instead of derived classes...

...This is particularly useful in automated integration tests where you have a lot of setup/tear down.  In such cases it often makes sense to keep state in a class designed to encapsulate the pattern rather than rely on the unit test fixture.  This way you can easily support sharing the skeleton of the test suite between fixtures, without relying on (sometimes shoddy) test fixture inheritance.  It also might be more amenable to parallelization, depending on the implementation of your tests.

```
var test = new MyFancyUITest
{
    // I usually name these things in a more test specific manner...
    Setup = () => { /* ... */ },
    TearDown = () => { /* ... */ },
};
test.Execute();
```

#### Intellisense Support

> outside users of the function see unnamed parameters - sometimes this is helpfull although it would be nice to be able to name them.

Use a named delegate - I believe this will get you at least some Intellisense for the parameters (probably just the names, less likely XML docs - please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate int DoSomethingImpl(int foo, int bizBar);
    public DoSomethingImpl DoSomething = (x, y) => { return x + y; }
}
```

Comment: @alan2here: Edited to round out this answer as advice rather than leaving readers to draw their own conclusions.  Also thought of another use case that matches the methods-as-delegates paradigm, tho not as public fields.

Comment: Nulls don't have to be checked before a delegate is called, only if it might be null, it's always the case that calling the member might result in code running that then fails.

Comment: @alan2here: Public fields might be null unless you can guarantee they aren't.  Any time you're passed an instance from elsewhere in code, the field might be null, so you'll have to do a null check.  The only time you can skip the check is if you constructed the instance of the class inside the current method.  Normal methods aren't themselves nullable, but fields are.  With normal methods you'd have to check the object for being null, but not each method.

Comment: Except in the cases, which in some programs could be every case, where it can be meaningfully handled, whats going to happen if you check, and a delegate method turns out to be null, thats better than a null exception? I've updated the question btw, you'll probbably prefer the introductory sentences now.

Comment: @alan2here: I have a rebuttal to that, but I think we'll be rabbit-holing.  My main point is that a standard method can never be null, and the fact that you can null out fields can cause a problem.  Another way to solve this is to wrap private fields with public properties, check for null in the setter, and throw the `ArgumentNullException` there.  I will edit my answer to recommend this and back off the "always have to check" statement.

Answer (score 2):

The second one, in my opinion, offers absolutely *no* advantage over the first one. It's much less readable, is probably less efficient (given that `Invoke` has to be implied) and isn't more concise at all. What's more, if you ever use reflection it won't show up as being a method so if you do that to replace your methods in every class, you might break something that seems like it should work. In Visual Studio, the IntelliSense won't include a description of the method since you can't put XML comments on delegates (at least, not in the same way you would put them on normal methods) and you don't know what they point to anyway, unless it's readonly (but what if the constructor changed it?) and it will show up as a field, not a method, which is confusing.

The only time you should really use lambdas is in methods where closures are required, or when it's offers a significant convenience advantage. Otherwise, you're just decreasing readability (basically the readability of my first paragraph versus the current one) and breaking compatibility with previous versions of C#.

Comment: I mystified.  When would you be faced with a choice between a function and a delegate?  They are used for totally different things.  It is like saying the `+` operator is more useful than the `=` assignment.

Comment: @Hogan: Not sure what you're referring to - the OP, or the answer?  And which line(s) specifically?  The OP implies the choice.  This answer responds to the OP's consideration of the choice.

Comment: -1 "Confusing", "readable" are highly subjective criteria. I happen to find them perfectly readable, and I guess most functional programmers would have no trouble reading them, and possibly even prefer them. If you happen to rely that much on reflection, you have much bigger issues than methods vs funcs.

Comment: I'm sorry, @MauricioScheffer, but that's a *really bad reason*. That's like saying there's no reason to use newlines or to indent your code because the readability of whitespace is highly subjective. -1 to that.

Comment: @minitech : it seems you're confusing readability with obfuscation.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: No, I'm not. You're being pedantic and ignoring the rest of my points. (And obfuscation usually changes the compiled result regardless.)

Comment: @minitech : I apologize if I was pedantic or offensive in any way. I assure you it was never my intention. Obfuscation is not limited to compiled results, see http://www.ioccc.org/ for examples and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code for definition.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid delegate properties/fields as method replacements for public methods. For private methods it's a tool, but not one I use very often.

- instance delegate fields have a per instance memory cost. Probably a premature optimization for most classes, but still something to keep in mind.
- Your code uses a public mutable field, which can be changed at any time. That hurts encapsulation.
- If you use the field initializer syntax, you can't access `this`. So field initializer syntax is mainly useful for static methods.
- Makes static analysis much harder, since the implementation of that method isn't known at compile-time.

There are some cases where delegate properties/fields might be useful:

- Handlers of some sort. Especially if multi-casting (and thus the event subscription pattern) doesn't make much sense
- Assigning something that can't be easily described by a simple method body. Such as a memoized function.
- The delegate is runtime generated or at least its value is only decided at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Using a closure over local variables is an alternative to using a method and private fields. I strongly dislike classes with lots of fields, especially if some of these fields are only used by two methods or less. In these situations, using a delegate in a field can be preferable to conventional methods

```
class MyClassConventional {
  int? someValue; // When Mark() is called, remember the value so that we can do something with it in Process(). Not used in any other method.
  int X;

  void Mark() {
    someValue = X;
  }

  void Process() {
    // Do something with someValue.Value
  }
}

class MyClassClosure {
  int X;

  Action Process = null;

  void Mark() {
    int someValue = X;
    Process = () => { // Do something with someValue };
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question presents a false dichotomy - between functions, and a delegate with an equivalent signature. The main difference is that one of the two you should only use if there are no other choices. Use this in your day to day work, and it will be thrown out of any code review.

The benefits that have been mentioned are *far* outweighed by the fact that there is almost never a reason to write code that is so obscure; especially when this code makes it look like you don't know how to program C#.

I urge anyone reading this to ignore any of the benefits which have been stated, since they are all overwhelmed by the fact that this is the kind of code that demonstrates that you do not know how to program in C#.

The only exception to that rule is if you have a need for one of the benefits, and that need can't be satisfied in any other way. In that case, you'll need to write more comment than code to explain why you have a good reason to do it. Be prepared to answer as clearly as Eric Lippert did. You'd better be able to explain as well as Eric does that you can't accomplish your requirements and write understandable code at the same time.

Comment: -1 This answer adds no value. Code review and job-losing warnings may apply to you, but in principle I'd have no trouble with such sort of code; so I wouldn't generalize that. "Obscurity" arguments again very much apply to you; don't generalize. I don't find this obscure at all, and I guess many functional programmers would be perfectly comfortable with it. "you do not know how to program in C#." -> Mainstream languages like C# are getting more and more functional, get used to it. See http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1406

Comment: The way you dismiss this option doesn't explain the advantages or disadvantages of either option.  *why* are methods preferable to delegates in this case?  *why* is one the "default" option?  Just because you have become entrenched in a certain style of coding in C# doesn't mean it is the only way.  However I agree with the thrust of your argument.  There are disadvantages of doing delegates, and those disadvantages will outweigh their use as a *default* option.  Using them like this should be an exception rather than a default way to do business, thus needs to be justified.