# readonly Func versus methods, performance implications/under the hood stuff

Tags: c#, .net, performance, methods, func

Are there any performance implications for implementing referentially transparent methods as static readonly Funcs instead of simply as methods? Personally I find the Func versions more readable, but maybe the traditional way is more efficient.

This:

```
static readonly Func<DateTime, DateTime> TruncateDay =
  date => date.AddHours(-date.Hour)
              .AddMinutes(-date.Minute)
              .AddSeconds(-date.Second)
              .AddMilliseconds(-date.Millisecond);

static readonly Func<DateTime, DateTime> TruncateMonth =
  date => TruncateDay(date).AddDays(1 - date.Day);

static readonly Func<DateTime, DateTime> TruncateYear =
  date => TruncateMonth(date).AddMonths(1 - date.Month);

static readonly Func<DateTime, int> QuarterSwitch =
  date => Switch(date.Month % 3, 0,
            Case(1, 3),
            Case(2, 4),
            Case(0, 5));
```

Versus this:

```
static DateTime TruncateDay (DateTime date) 
{ 
  return date.AddHours(-date.Hour)
             .AddMinutes(-date.Minute)
             .AddSeconds(-date.Second)
             .AddMilliseconds(-date.Millisecond);
}

static DateTime TruncateMonth (DateTime date)
{ 
  return TruncateDay(date).AddDays(1 - date.Day);
}

static DateTime TruncateYear (DateTime date)
{
  return TruncateMonth(date).AddMonths(1 - date.Month);
}

static int QuarterSwitch (DateTime date)
{ 
  return Switch(date.Month % 3, 0,
           Case(1, 3),
           Case(2, 4),
           Case(0, 5));
}
```

How are these represented internally? What does the compiler translate each to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# more advantages or disadvantages to delegate members over classic functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028059/c-sharp-more-advantages-or-disadvantages-to-delegate-members-over-classic-functi)

Comment: I'd say not, cause delegates are delegates, methods are methods. once you declare a method it can't be anything else. Whereas delegates can change which method they point to at any time. My question is not about delegates.

Comment: I'm also more interested in which is faster, and the differences between the two under the hood, as opposed to Advantages/Disadvantages

Comment: FYI, `TruncateDay` already exists as the `Date` property on the `DateTime` value, and is about 5 times faster than your implementation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

Comment: Ahh, thankyou! I did have a long search before resorting to this. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood, the compiler creates 2 additional members for each `Func` method:

1. A static method that is essentially the same as in the traditional approach.
2. A 'cached delegate' field that is of the same type as your delegate.

The reason for the cached delegate field is that the compiler needs this for anonymous methods that appear elsewhere in code. The compiler doesn't optimize away the field in this case.

The class also requires a static constructor to initialize those two fields for each method.

Some of the performance implications are:

- There is a small overhead in having to call the private static function. This overhead increases as the size of the argument list increases.
- `Func` methods can never be inlined. This can make a big difference for very small methods.
- The metadata for your class will be about 3x larger. This isn't free, but its effects are hard to quantify.

Some of the other drawbacks of using this are:

- Overloading is not possible.
- Parameter names are not picked up in Intellisense.
- It violates expectations in several ways, including the fact that the methods appear as fields in the statement completion list.

Answer (score 3):

Trying your `TruncateDay` in a simple loop, I got the method coming out as very slightly faster - close enough that the slowest runs with the method were slower than the fastest with the delegate, but still just about consistent that the delegate tended to be just a tiny bit less performant.

I then tried with a version that just returns the value passed to it. My plan being to have a method that should definitely be inlinable, and the method version was about 5 times faster than the delegate version. The obvious conclusion is that the method was indeed inlined, and the delegate wasn't, though that is of course conjecture.

Still, it's enough to suggest that there are at least some optimisations that are made for methods that aren't made for delegates. It's not unreasonable to consider that there might be yet more.

Comment: Empirical data collection.  Whoda thunk? :)

Comment: Of course, since we've expression body syntax now, anyone who finds the syntax in the question more readable will likely find that more readable still, so that reason at least is no longer one for doing as they were.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods will be much faster if their bodys themselves are cheap. If the body is expensive it does not matter.

The JIT cannot inline delegate contents and it has to use an indirect call. Both of which is terrible (for cheap methods).

Also, from a code quality perspective this is inacceptable:

- More code
- For most people less readable because they are used to the traditional style
- No refactoring support
- Against conventional idioms
- More complex

I strongly recommend that you just go with the traditional way in this case. If I was the project lead I would not tolerate such code without a special reason.

Comment: +1, also these would make good extension methods, which is only possible if they are... methods.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I answered the question, and in addition I provided architectural advice. It is a courtesy to leave a comment why you downvoted.

Comment: I completely agree with your assessment and disagree with the downvote, especially since no comment was provided.  So... I upvoted to offset. :)

Answer (score 0):

It helps me.hoping it will do the same for you.

```
grid.Sort.Enabled = false;
grid.Data Source = _data source_;

//Add a single object to the beginning of the grid
grid.Nodes.Insert(0, _new_object_);

//Add a single object to the beginning of the binding list
I Binding List bl = ...;
bl.Insert(0, _new_object_);
```